How can I make a heatmap with density-variable cell size?
I would like to reproduce this heatmap, wherein each cell contains "at least 10 sources" (excerpt from original publication" such that cell size is inversely proportional to the density of sources contained within it. Cell colour is determined by the average of some additional variable, z, of the enclosed sources. Figure 8 of Donley et al. 2012
So far, I have used np.histogram2d to generate a similar plot but with evenly-sized cells. This roughly conveys the trend I'd like to highlight, but I would really like to be able to replicate the variable cell-size approach. I don't believe this is close to the correct approach, so I'm not sure how helpful my current code will be, but please find it below! I'm relatively new to coding and frankly have no idea how to approach this task, so any guidance would be greatly appreciated! Thank you for your time :) my attempt :)
here is the relevant excerpt of my code:
x_bin_size = 0.3
y_bin_size = 0.3

x_min, x_max = np.min(x), np.max(x)
y_min, y_max = np.min(y), np.max(y)
    
num_bins_x = int(np.ceil((x_max - x_min) / x_bin_size))
num_bins_y = int(np.ceil((y_max - y_min) / y_bin_size))

hm, xedge, yedge = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins = [num_bins_x, num_bins_y], weights = z)
counts, _, _ = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins = [num_bins_x, num_bins_y])

avg_heatmap = np.divide(hm, counts, out = np.zeros_like(hm), where = counts != 0)
avg_heatmap_masked = np.ma.masked_where(avg_heatmap == 0, avg_heatmap)

c = ax.pcolormesh(xedge, yedge, avg_heatmap_masked.T, cmap = cmap, shading = 'auto')


[ask] and [mre]

don;t explain us what you have used so far, instead show us the code.

Apologies, I have now added the relevant code! I didn't add it originally as I thought my approach was completely incorrect and thus wouldn't be helpful. This is my first time asking a question on here, I'm sorry for the inadequate communication!

I can't find a simple "off-the-shelf" implementation, but its looks like you'll have to code up one of two approaches: 1) (divide and conquer) a top-down recursive splitting algorithm (like a decision tree), whereby you recursively split the samples down the middle into nodes (switching between splitting in x then y dimensions) with a stopping criterion that a nodes contains at least 10 sources, 2) (merge) a bottom up approach that does a 2d histogram with a large number of bins (so each may only contain 1 source), and then merges adjacent bins until they contain at least 10 sources.

Thanks for your response Matt (and for formatting my code excerpt above) - it looks like we landed on a similar idea. I gave it some thought after posting and ended up writing a script that, in short, generates a grid over the plot space, splits 'cells' (in the x or y direction) that don't meet the threshold criteria, recounts, and then repeats the splitting process until all cells meet the provided criteria. It will then average the values of a given column, z, for the sources within each cell and assign a colour on that basis. It needs some refining, but it gets the job done for now!
